# How and when to use Return statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand the concepts of functions and methods but while practicing, I am getting confused in different situations like how, where and when to exactly use `return` statements?
So here, are two parts of codes from separate operations.

code 1:

```
var john = {
     fname : 'John',
     mass : 45,
     age  : 24,
     height : 2,
     calculateBMI : function(){
         this.bmi = this.mass/(this.height * this.height);
         return this.bmi;
         
     }
```

code 2:

```
var adi ={
    fName : "adi",
    bills : [124,48,268,180,242],
    calculateTips : function(){
          this.tips =[];
          this.totalValue = [];

      for(var i=0; i<this.bills.length;i++){
          var percentage;
          var bill = this.bills[i]
          
          if(bill<50){
              percentage = 0.2;
          }else if(bill>=50 && bill<200){
              percentage = 0.15;
          }else{
              percentage = 0.1;
          }
          this.tips[i] = percentage * bill;
          this.totalValue[i] = bill + bill * percentage;
```

Comment: What on Earth does this have to do with Java or Python?

Comment: What's the question? Use return when you done with function and want to exit to parent scope. With or without any value

Comment: Return is used in a function to stop execution of the function and return the specified value where the function was called. Javascript allows a function to not have a return, which means the function will execute until its end, then return undefined.

Comment: [MDN - return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: You can return something inside a function to leave the function and bring the resulting value outside of the function scope...  You don't return something inside a variable...  Please study more about functions and data types before coming here to ask questions, this is the extreme basics of programming...

Comment: @Khant ,ok brother . 

Comment: Remove tag from title as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles; Grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement does two main things,it ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

For exapmle in your first code the function takes the value of the calculateBMI function and returns it to the caller.

If there was another line of code in the function after the return, the computer wasnt going to run it because the function stopped after the "return".

Im adding a link to the docs about return: [return - JS MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: Thanks for the info , that 3rd line is really helpful. cleared big part of my doubt.

Comment: glad to help :)
you got the part of returning the value to the caller?

Comment: Yeah , actually i understood most of the theoretical part ,but this "Where to place return" was confusing and i think that was the biggest thing behind the rest of the doubts linked with Return . I think i understand the its role now. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

return statement is doing 3 main works of our code blocks
1- return can stop some code loop
like foreach , while loop are there.
2- return can get some data from the functions ( methods )
like your first code
3 - return can get some data from another class or service.

return is the last or final line of any code block.

actually return is using for mainly data transfers